# SVC sigmoid kernel is not working properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am testing an SVM with a sigmoid kernel on the iris data using sklearn and SVC. Its performance is extremely poor with an accuracy of 25 %. I'm using exactly the same code and normalizing the features as https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-svm-parameter-tuning-8bfe6b8a452c (sigmoid section) which should increase performance substantially. However, I am not able to reproduce his results and the accuracy only increases to 33 %.

Using other kernels (e.g linear kernel) produces good results (accuracy of 82 %).
Could there be an issue within the SVC(kernel = 'sigmoid') function?

Python code to reproduce problem:

```py
##sigmoid iris example
from sklearn import datasets 
iris = datasets.load_iris()
from sklearn.svm import SVC 

sepal_length = iris.data[:,0] 
sepal_width = iris.data[:,1]

#assessing performance of sigmoid SVM
clf = SVC(kernel='sigmoid') 
clf.fit(np.c_[sepal_length, sepal_width], iris.target) 
pr=clf.predict(np.c_[sepal_length, sepal_width])
pd.DataFrame(classification_report(iris.target, pr, output_dict=True))

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import sigmoid_kernel 
sigmoid_kernel(np.c_[sepal_length, sepal_width]) 

#normalizing features
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize 
sepal_length_norm = normalize(sepal_length.reshape(1, -1))[0] 
sepal_width_norm = normalize(sepal_width.reshape(1, -1))[0] 
clf.fit(np.c_[sepal_length_norm, sepal_width_norm], iris.target) 
sigmoid_kernel(np.c_[sepal_length_norm, sepal_width_norm]) 

#assessing perfomance of sigmoid SVM with normalized features
pr_norm=clf.predict(np.c_[sepal_length_norm, sepal_width_norm])
pd.DataFrame(classification_report(iris.target, pr_norm, output_dict=True))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what's happening. In sklearn releases pre [0.22](https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) the default `gamma` parameter passed to the SVC was "auto", and in subsequent releases this was changed to "scale". The author of the article seems to have been using a previous version and therefore implicitly passing `gamma="auto"` (he mentions that the "current default setting for gamma is ‘auto’"). So if you're on the latest release of sklearn (0.23.2), you'll want to explicitly pass `gamma='auto'` when instantiating the SVC:

```
clf = SVC(kernel='sigmoid',gamma='auto') 
#normalizing features
sepal_length_norm = normalize(sepal_length.reshape(1, -1))[0] 
sepal_width_norm = normalize(sepal_width.reshape(1, -1))[0] 

clf.fit(np.c_[sepal_length_norm, sepal_width_norm], iris.target)
```

[image]

So now when you print the classification report:

```
pr_norm=clf.predict(np.c_[sepal_length_norm, sepal_width_norm])
print(pd.DataFrame(classification_report(iris.target, pr_norm, output_dict=True)))

#                    0          1          2  accuracy   macro avg  weighted avg
# precision   0.907407   0.650000   0.750000  0.766667    0.769136      0.769136
# recall      0.980000   0.780000   0.540000  0.766667    0.766667      0.766667
# f1-score    0.942308   0.709091   0.627907  0.766667    0.759769      0.759769
# support    50.000000  50.000000  50.000000  0.766667  150.000000    150.000000
```

What would explain the 33% accuracy you were seeing is the fact that the default `gamma` is "scale", which then places all predictions in a single region of the decision plane, and as the targets are split into thirds you get a maximum accuracy of 33.3%:

```
clf = SVC(kernel='sigmoid') 
#normalizing features
sepal_length_norm = normalize(sepal_length.reshape(1, -1))[0] 
sepal_width_norm = normalize(sepal_width.reshape(1, -1))[0] 

clf.fit(np.c_[sepal_length_norm, sepal_width_norm], iris.target) 

X = np.c_[sepal_length_norm, sepal_width_norm]
```

[image]

```
pr_norm=clf.predict(np.c_[sepal_length_norm, sepal_width_norm])
print(pd.DataFrame(classification_report(iris.target, pr_norm, output_dict=True)))

#               0     1          2  accuracy   macro avg  weighted avg
# precision   0.0   0.0   0.333333  0.333333    0.111111      0.111111
# recall      0.0   0.0   1.000000  0.333333    0.333333      0.333333
# f1-score    0.0   0.0   0.500000  0.333333    0.166667      0.166667
# support    50.0  50.0  50.000000  0.333333  150.000000    150.000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate answer!